# “Experimentally determined” vs. “determined experimentally”

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, past-participles

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. The numbers are experimentally determined.
> 2. The numbers are determined experimentally.

Are both (not) correct and if only one of them is correct, what is the underlying rule?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should adverbs be placed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23868/where-should-adverbs-be-placed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no significant difference. It's just a matter of style.

LATER: OP's particular word-pair doesn't occur often enough to easily establish usage figures for the two alternative orders, but I think [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=chosen%20arbitrarily,arbitrarily%20chosen&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows a clear tendency to write *arbitrarily chosen* rather than *chosen arbitrarily* (a grammatically and semantically similar example).

On no authority but my own, I suggest the choice of word order may sometimes be influenced by a tendency to write the contextually more significant word first. In my particular example, for instance, I believe the *arbitrary* nature of the choice is likely to be more in the writer's mind than the fact of a 'choice' being made at all.